# Python Multiprocessing - TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm having the following Problem. I want to implement a web crawler, so far this worked but it was so slow, that I tried to use multiprocessing for fetching the URLs.
Unfortunately I'm not very experienced at this field.
After some reading the easiest way seemed to me to use the `map` method from `multiprocessing.pool` for this.

But I constantly get the following error:

```
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
```

I found very few cases with the same error and they unfortunately did not help me.

I created a stripped version of my code which can reproduce the error:

```
import multiprocessing

class TestCrawler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.queue = self.m.Queue()
        for i in range(50):
            self.queue.put(str(i))
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)



    def mainloop(self):
        self.process_next_url(self.queue)

        while True:
            self.pool.map(self.process_next_url, (self.queue,))                

    def process_next_url(self, queue):
        url = queue.get()
        print(url)


c = TestCrawler()
c.mainloop()
```

I would be very thankful about any help or suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Question**: But I constantly get the following error:

The Error you'r getting is missleading, the reason are

```
self.queue = self.m.Queue()
```

Move the `Queue` instantiation Outside the `class TestCrawler`.
This leads to another Error:

> NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled

The reason are:

```
self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
```

Both Errors are indicating that `pickle` can't find the `class Members`.

> **Note**: Endless Loop!
>   Your following `while` Loop leads to a Endless Loop!
>   This will **overload** your System!
>   Furthermore, your `pool.map(...` starts only **one** `Process` with **one** Task!
>
> ```
>     while True:
>         self.pool.map(self.process_next_url, (self.queue,))
> ```

I suggest reading [The Examples that demonstrates the use of a pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

---

Change to the following:

```
class TestCrawler:
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        # Assign the Global task to class member
        self.queue = tasks
        for i in range(50):
            self.queue.put(str(i))

    def mainloop(self):
        # Instantiate the pool local
        pool = mp.Pool(6)
        for n in range(50):
            # .map requires a Parameter pass None
            pool.map(self.process_next_url, (None,))

    # None is passed
    def process_next_url(self, dummy):
        url = self.queue.get()
        print(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Create the Queue as Global
  tasks = mp.Manager().Queue()
  # Pass the Queue to your class TestCrawler
  c = TestCrawler(tasks)
  c.mainloop()
```

---

This Example starts 5 Processes each processing 10 Tasks(urls):

```
class TestCrawler2:
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        self.tasks = tasks

    def start(self):
        pool = mp.Pool(5)
        pool.map(self.process_url, self.tasks)

    def process_url(self, url):
        print('self.process_url({})'.format(url))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tasks = ['url{}'.format(n) for n in range(50)]
    TestCrawler2(tasks).start()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It worked for the short example, but somehow when I changed it in my program that way I still have the same problem. Could you maybe send me some resources which explain the pickling? When looking for this I mostly get texts about the pickle module.

Comment: @blue: [Edit] your Question and show the **args=** you are using for `pool.map(...`, I assume you are still trying to pass a `muliprocessing` object which is impossible!

Comment: this code works with 'map' method only and not with apply_async